# QSettings replaces slashes with backslashes (registry)

Tags: windows, qt, registry, qsettings

I read the registry with QSettings. The key I want to read is this:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Source OS (Updated on 8/1/2015 02:45:41)

Since the key name **`Source OS (Updated on 8/1/2015 02:45:41)`** is dynamic, I just open

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\Setup", QSettings::NativeFormat);
```

and run recursive through the settings.childGroups() and build my key with this:

```
QString key = settings.fileName() + "\\" + settings.group();
```

But this results in:

> \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Source OS (Updated on 8\1\2015 02:45:41)

As you can see the slashes are now backslashes and I cannot distinguish between name and path pieces.

Any idea why QSettings converts the slashes into backslashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the QSettings [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#section-and-key-syntax):

> **Do not use slashes (`'/'` and `'\'`) in section or key names**; the backslash character is used to separate sub keys (see below). On windows `'\'` are converted by `QSettings` to `'/'`, which makes them identical.

Generally, the idea of dynamic registry key names is not so good. I think the better approach is to create two separate values inside your key – `Source OS` and `Updated On` values.

Comment: i know... but the key ist generated by the update to windows 10 - i have no influence

Comment: @wutzebaer Then, unfortunately, you'll have to access registry via **WinAPI**, I guess.